# How can I load different ReactNative bundles in a native Android app?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a native Android app and two independent `ReactNative` bundles which I need to load when user activates one or another within the native app. Each bundled ReactNative app also uses [react-navigation/native](https://reactnavigation.org/) for in-app navigation, which forces me to use `ReactActivity` as my base activity and `ReactApplication` as my base application class.

I discovered this article to [load multiple react native bundles in runtime](https://varunon9.medium.com/loading-multiple-bundles-in-react-native-code-splitting-using-metro-44d45530e958) but it uses regular activity for each separate bundle instantiating a new `ReactInstanceManager` for each activity. Having `ReactApplication` as my based app class forces me to create and return RN host once in the application itself:

```
class MyCoolApplication: Application(), ReactApplication {

     private val mReactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost = object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        ...

        override fun getBundleAssetName(): String? {
            return "mycoolapp2.bundle" // I also have "mycoolapp1.bundle"
        }

        ...
    }

    override fun getReactNativeHost(): ReactNativeHost {
       return mReactNativeHost
    }
}
```

Basically with that I'm limited to a single host which is associated with a single bundle. How do I support multiple React Native bundles?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following way, maybe not the only one, but it works as expected. Basically the idea is to implement the required by `ReactApplication` inheritance method as below and make sure it is not going to be used:

```java
@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    throw new NotImplementedError();
}
```

And then, when you need to load any react native bundle, create an React Native activity, override delegate and handle the rest within the delegate:

```kotlin
class GenericReactNativeActivity: ReactActivity() {
    ...
    override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate? {
        return GenericReactNativeActivityDelegate(this)
    }
}

class GenericReactNativeActivityDelegate(private val mActivity: ReactActivity?) :
    ReactActivityDelegate(mActivity, null) {

    override fun getMainComponentName(): String {
        // return your main component name
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // init as needed
    }

    override fun getReactNativeHost(): ReactNativeHost {
        // return host which handles bundle name
    }

    override fun getLaunchOptions(): Bundle? {
        // return your startup params
    }
}
```